# Tensorflow - do I need to learn computer vision before linear (timeseries) regression?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, time-series, linear-regression

I'm a newbie to tensorflow / keras and I am currently working my way through Deep Learning with Python (2nd edition) by Francois Chollet.

I understand the basics of Computer vision and the MNIST examples but I'm not really interested in computer vision.

My question is do you think it would be safe to skip the computer vision chapters and just focus on my interest(s) in regression machine learning + time series forecasting?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer vision is not needed to learn time series forecasting.
Also, as you have mentioned Machine Learning and regression in that case Deep learning itself is optional. you can build model without using Deep Learning.
If you want to use LSTM in Time Series, then you need Deep Learning.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know CV to do well in time series forecasting! Your interest in regression and ML algorithms can be developed without having to develop any skills in CV. You can check out deep learning algorithms for regression problems if you're interested but Computer Vision isn't necessary.